# Installing Ubuntu server create problem in my Dell R540

Tags: server, software-installation, dell, iso

My problem is that when i started install ubuntu server in my server machine(Dell R540), it starts showing me the problem that "there was a problem completing the installation" and it restart with same language prompt again. so I detect the problem and it is not with my hardware machine but it is because of the ISO fie I downloaded from the ubuntu official website.
I firstly downloaded the iso from here : https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VPo1.png

so this iso file is responding with "there was a problem completing the installation"
after that I downloaded another ISO from here : http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkuPS.png

It smoothly worked so the question is why these two are behaving differently.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, If you don't mind: Why did you choose 18.04, while 20.04 is the current LTS?

Comment: I know that there is 20.04 available but it is not stable enough so that's why..!!